# JPA: How do I write an order by clause for an item in a set?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sql-order-by, jpa-2.0

I'm using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4.1.0.Final.  I have this in my Hibernate entity …

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns =     @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"))
private Set<Address> addresses;
```

In which the Address entity has this field:

```
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
```

How do I write an order by clause for a query on User objects to order by the first email address in this set, given the fact the user might not be linked to any address objects at all?  I have tried

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
final Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);
...
Expression orderByExpr = orderByRoot.get(orderByCol).get("addresses").get("email");
criteria.orderBy(orderByExpr);
```

But get the error …

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [email] against path
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.unknownAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:192)
    at org.mainco.subco.user.repo.UserDaoImpl.addOrderByCol(UserDaoImpl.java:446)
    at org.mainco.subco.user.repo.UserDaoImpl.buildFindUsersQuery(UserDaoImpl.java:342)
    at org.mainco.subco.user.repo.UserDaoImpl.findUsers(UserDaoImpl.java:153)
    at org.mainco.subco.user.repo.UserDao2IT.testFindOrderByEmail(UserDao2IT.java:558)
```

**Edit:** Here is the rough code I have as recommended by Andrei I.  It results in an error I listed in the comment.

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
final Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);
...
final Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);
 Join<User, Address> addr = user.join("addresses", JoinType.LEFT);
 orderByExpr = addr.get("email"); 
 criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(orderByExpr));
…            
return criteria.where(builder.and(…))
            .select(user);
```

Comment: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/order check the solution in the last

Comment: Where in this link does it address ordering by a single element in a set using CriteriaBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
final CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);
final Root<User> user = query.from(User.class);
query.select(user);//this one was missed.

SetJoin<User, Address> addr = user.joinSet("addresses", JoinType.LEFT);

query.orderBy( builder.asc(addr.get("email")) );
```

PS: as the `addresses` field is a set, it is not ordered, meaning it is not clear which one in the list will be considered. Also in SQL you need some criteria that defines the "first" element.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, but it resulted in the error, "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No explicit selection and an implicit one cold not be determined".

Comment: That is another question/problem, as you forgot to select the root. I updated my answer to solve also this problem.

Comment: Yes, I was already doing that.  I edited my answer to show you how I inserted the order by lines you provided.  If I comment them out, everything works fine (except the ordering) but if I include your lines, I get the exception that I listed.

Comment: Yes, I put in your lines and I get that exception.

Comment: Interesting. I corrected my answer in which I used `joinSet()` instead of `join()`.

Comment: I appreciate your keeping up with this.  I tried your suggestion but got the same "No explicit selection and an implicit ..." exception.  One question -- how does the expression, 'addr.get("email")', know to pick the first element of the set?

Comment: As I said in the answer, in a `Set` there is no ordering, meaning the rows in the query will be sorted by an entry (not clear which one). You should define "first". Do you mean to sort by the email address with the lowest ID? If so, than this is complicated to write/understand, and IMHO not worth the time.

Comment: I have tested the code and it works as I expected it without any exceptions. The equivalent SQL query is (with a set of Phone instead of Address): `select user0_.id as id47_, user0_.address_id as address3_47_, user0_.name as name47_ from user user0_ left outer join user_Phone phones1_ on user0_.id=phones1_.user_id left outer join Phone phone2_ on phones1_.phones_id=phone2_.id order by phone2_.number asc`

Comment: Could you include the Hibernate entity definitions you used, unless they were the same as what I had?

Comment: It is actually the same as your code: http://pastebin.com/C7LmWh6F Also just to make sure that you don't make other errors: in an entity hierarchy annotate either the fields, or the accessors/getters (except you know how to override that).